# SMS Notification

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am working on a fake SMS app.The fake SMS created but the notification wasn't received.
Please guide me to get the original notification from device SMS app.
This is my code:

```
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("address", phoneNumber);
        values.put("body", message);
        values.put("date",  String.valueOf(startTime));
        getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), values);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many "device SMS apps". Whether they show a notification or not is up to them.

Many of those that do will do so based upon receiving the SMS via an SMS broadcast. And, hopefully most of those [require that the sender of this broadcast be the system](http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/10/06/secured-broadcasts-sms-clients.html), to prevent malware authors from sending spoof broadcasts.

And, your code will not work on Android 4.4+ anyway, as [you can no longer write to the SMS `ContentProvider` unless you are the user's default SMS client](http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/10/14/sms-apps-warned-you.html).